# Module Not Found - when using an imported function

Tags: python, function, module

This is my file structure

```
root
|- src
|  |-bot
|  | |-conf
|  | | |-data.py
|  | |-model.py 
|- main.py
```

Code for my model.py

```
from conf.data import old_data

def somemodel(new_data):
  old_data += new_data
  (more working with data)
```

The code I am running in main.py

```
from src.bot.model import somemodel

def main():
  somemodel(new_data)
```

What I am trying to do is, build a model with some data and then use that model in my `main.py` file.

When importing data from `data.py` in `model.py`, everything works fine. But when I am trying to import `somemodel` function by running `main.py` in root, I am getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conf'
```

I tried everything but nothing seems to work. Why is my code behaving in this manner? How do I fix it?

**Edit** - Found the problem. When I run `model.py` the imports work fine because the modules are looked from the scope of `bot`, therefore, modules are found. But when I am calling the somemodel function from `main.py`. The modules of `model.py` are being looked in the `root` scope, which has no conf folder, therefore the program throws a `ModuleNotFoundError` error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Show us how you are running the code.  What is the exact command, and what is the current working directory?

Comment: My pwd is root. My python path is set to a venv outside my root. So my exact command is "python main.py"

Comment: I actually figured out why this is happening, when I'm calling somemodel from main.py,  and the control is passed to model.py, it tries looking for conf from the scope of root instead of looking from the scope of bot. Since there is no conf in root directory, it throws a ModuleNotFound Error.  I now know why it is happening but i can't figure out how to fix this

Comment: One way would be to set your PYTHONPATH environment variable to the root folder, and then write all your imports as full paths from root.  i.e. `from src.bot.conf.data import whatever`